# ArangoDB: How to list or export all documents in a database, regardless of collections

Tags: arangodb

I see that there are APIs for listing and exporting all documents within a given collection, but I need to list/export all documents (ids) in all collections in a database simultaneously. (This is for V&V of a service I'm developing). Is this possible, or must I query for each collection one at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arangodump` will dump all the collections within a database, but the output format for a DOCUMENT is like this:

```
{"type":2300,"data": DOCUMENT}
```

There is one such entry per document in a per-collection file, which is named like so:

```
COLLECTION_07cf4f8f5d8b76282917320715dda2ad.data.json
```

It would be easy enough to extract DOCUMENT, e.g. using jq one would basically write: `jq .data`

`arangoexport` does allow one to specify multiple collections in a single invocation, but they must be specified explicitly.

One possibility for automating the use of `arangoexport` would be to use `arangosh` to generate the collection names in a specific database (using `db._collections()`), and then construct the appropriate `arangoexport` command or commands.